# Hidden form in codeigniter not passing data

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

I try to post some data in a form with a hidden field:

```
$data_acc=array('db_id'=>$id,
'db_lastname'=>$lastname,
'db_name'=>$name,
'db_phone'=>$phone,
'db_city'=>$city,
'db_email'=>$email
);
var_dump($data_acc);
form_hidden($data_acc);
```

var dump returns this :

```
array(6) { ["db_id"]=> string(1) "6" 
["db_lastname"]=> string(0) "" 
["db_name"]=> string(0) "" 
["db_phone"]=> string(0) "" 
["db_city"]=> string(0) "" 
["db_email"]=> string(22) "xxx@xxx.com" }
```

When i try to access it from the page function i post to, it can't find it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you read http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html ?

Comment: I've read it several times. Why? what i've done wrong?

Comment: I don't know. Did you try `var_dump($_POST)` on the page you are submitting to?

Comment: Yes, its echoing only the normal input fields.

Comment: And did you look at the html to verify the hidden inputs are being generated correctly?

Comment: Actually they don't appear. Do you have any ideas why this happens? I have other fields like this on other pages that work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `echo` before `form_hidden()` so the hidden inputs are not being generated.

```
echo form_hidden($data_acc);
```

Comment: hi i dont have server of ECHO funtion installed is there any soltion?? my codes are allways show `<% PHP echo() on live servar`